# Ng-init fails to init value on load

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel, ng-init

When using ng-init in combination with an array there is never an init value. After trying all the possible options, i hope someone can find a fix for this problem.

*The html*

```
<select class="update-invisible" ng-model="user.level" ng-init="user.level" ng-change="updateUserlevel(user)" ng-options="userlevel.id as userlevel.label for userlevel in userlevels track by userlevel.id"></select>
```

**Note: the ngmodel (user.level) is an integer that specifies the current userlevel, in an user information object. In this object the userlevel has to be updated in order to change the users permission.**

*userlevels object, to match the user.level int to a string to display front end*

```
$scope.userlevels = [{
        id: 1,
        label: 'Regular user'
    },{
        id: 2,
        label: 'Administrator'
    }];
```

Comment: Can you create a fiddle to demonstrate your problem. It looks that you are using ng-init in a wrong manner.

Comment: problem is with your  track by. Do you really need track by there?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `ng-init` to evaluate an angular expression. The following snip sets the `level` property of the `user` scope object to 5.

```
<div ng-init="user.level = 5">
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with your track by , remove track by then it will work

```
<select class="update-invisible" ng-model="user.level = 1" ng-init="user.level" ng-change="updateUserlevel(user)" ng-options="userlevel.id as userlevel.label for userlevel in userlevels"></select>
```

**OR-ELSE**

```
<select class="update-invisible" ng-model="user.level" ng-init="user.level = 1" ng-change="updateUserlevel(user)" ng-options="userlevel.id as userlevel.label for userlevel in userlevels track by userlevel.id">
<option value="">--Select one Option--</option>
</select>
```

means include your own default option tag.